# Snowflake. How to change schema for all queries in all tiles in dashboard?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

There is a dashboard in Snowsight with some tiles and I want to change scheme in all tiles.
Smth like that:

```
set shcema_name=my_1;
select * from $schema_name.table_1
```

Answer (score 0):

Table name could be parametrized, but it has to be provided as single string:

```
set schema_name= 'my_1';
set table_1 = $schema_name || '.Table_1';

select * from TABLE($table_1);
-- or
select * from IDENTIFIER($table_1);
```